# Core Data slows to a crawl when editing a scrolling textview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsdocument

interesting problem here:

I've got a handful of textviews connected to a Core Data model.  Everything works fine, except one thing.

When I put information into a textview, the entire application slows to a crawl, invoking the beachball.

When I attached a Core Data Instrument to my app's process, NSManagedObjectContext save is being called with each character that is typed.  This lag is crippling the entire application.

To make things stranger, the problem is not consistent.  Sometimes the app decides it needs to write to the saved document (SQLite, XML, binary, doesn't matter) for each and every character that is typed into the textview, and other times it won't.

Any ideas?

Comment: Bonus: It appears that I can trigger the NSManagedContextObject save: when simply clicking on ANYTHING in the app, not just the TextView... what in the world....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Response**

I am updating this answer to reflect the reality of what was happening.

As patrickn stated in his original question he is developing a document-based app with Core Data. He eventually found that the document was returning YES for autoSavesInPlace. It turns out that this is the default behavior, which seems to have undesirable effect with NSManagedObjectContext.

[According to Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/DocumentBasedDesign/DocumentBasedDesign.html):

> In Mac OS X v10.7 and later, users don’t need to save documents
>   explicitly or be concerned about losing unsaved changes. Instead, the
>   system automatically writes document data to disk as necessary. Your
>   NSDocument subclass opts into this behavior by overriding the
>   autosavesInPlace class method to return YES. The ideal baseline for
>   saveless documents is this: The document data that users see in an
>   application window is identical to the document on disk at all times.

Sounds great, but they also say:

> Before you enable autosaving, consider the saving performance of your
>   application. If your application saves quickly, there is little reason
>   not to enable it. But if your application saves slowly, enabling
>   autosaving could cause periodic blocking of your user interface while
>   saving is happening.

Long story short, if you are developing a document-based app on Lion and are seeing questionable performance you will want to consider whether or not you should be returning YES for `autosavesInPlace`.

**Original Response**

If you really want to fix then you have to find out what is calling the save operation. This is not something that happens normally so I would take a very good look through your code and set breakpoints at every call to save.

Run through you app and you be able to find out where it is happening.

There is no reason why it would call it randomly, but if after doing this you find that it still is, then I would file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sosborn.  This application is entirely created through the xib, I didn't write a line of code.  That's not to say I'm unwilling to delve into the code, but I find it interesting that it seems to have issues running "out of the box" in this fashion.

Comment: In that case my guess is that you connected the textView to the save operation in IB. Right click on the textView in IB and see what it is connected to.

Comment: Checked all of my TextViews and none are linked to any actions.  They are only using bindings from Value -> an appropriate entity attribute.

Comment: Based on your comment about clicking anywhere, then check the actions for the window. Basically, if you started a new app and built everything in IB the only way for this to happen is if you assign the save action to something.

Comment: Thanks sosborn - I have right-clicked on every object in the doc window (First Responder, File's Owner, Window, Main Menu, on down the line through all 6 of my Array Controllers) and have found nothing bound to save related actions.

Is there a possibility that this issue could be related to Undo?

Comment: Update: after poking around the document implementation file, I saw the class method autoSavesInPlace returning YES.  I suspected that this might have something to do with it, and it turns out it did.  Something about the managedContext does not like this method to return YES, and feels compelled to perform incremental saves at inappropriate times.  Setting this method to return NO completely resolved my issue.


It's worth noting that this method is defaulted to return YES, so if you ever find yourself having save performance issues, try setting it to NO.  Thanks guys!

Comment: Sorry, I had totally missed that you were doing this in an document-based application even though you said so in the original question. This issue appears to be Lion only as it is related to the Versions feature. I am going to update my answer to reflect what you found.

Comment: I will say that interestingly, I have intermittently (even less often than before, seems completely erratic and unpredictable) ran into this issue STILL despite disabling autoSavesInPlace - I'm really quite at a loss as to why it's still manifesting this behavior.  To make matters worse, disabling this method also disables the Duplicate command in the File menu.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this suggestion, but if nothing more interesting come I would fall back to this one.

I would suggest adding a layer between Core Data and the UITextView that would buffer the information and launch the Core Data save once in a while. (instead of each char)

Comment: Thanks, Vince.  As I mentioned in my reply to sosborn, I didn't write any code for this app - it's purely created using point and click configuration in the .xib for the document (document-based application).  Given that information, how would you suggest adding said layer?